# I install the flutterwave package in laravel 8 and 9 but facing this issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, flutterwave

i run this command

composer install flutterwavedev/flutterwave-v3

give me this error.

Invalid argument flutterwavedev/flutterwave-v3. Use "composer require flutterwavedev/flutterwave-v3" instead to add packages to your composer.json.

when we run this command "composer require flutterwavedev/flutterwave-v3".

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- flutterwavedev/flutterwave-v3 1.0.0 requires monolog/monolog 1.* -> found monolog/monolog[1.0.0-RC1, ..., 1.x-dev] but the package is fixed to 2.6.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
- flutterwavedev/flutterwave-v3 1.0.1 requires vlucas/phpdotenv ^2.5 -> found vlucas/phpdotenv[v2.5.0, ..., 2.6.x-dev] but the package is fixed to v5.4.1 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
- Root composer.json requires flutterwavedev/flutterwave-v3 ^1.0 -> satisfiable by flutterwavedev/flutterwave-v3[1.0.0, 1.0.1].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require flutterwavedev/flutterwave-v3:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require flutterwavedev/flutterwave-v3:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

Comment: What is your issue? The error explicitly tells you that you want to install `flutterwavedev/flutterwave-v3` which requires `monolog/monolog 1.*` but your installation requires `monolog/monolog 2.6.0`. What is not clear ? what is your question here ?

Comment: Same issue with the version 1.0.1 of flutterwavedev/flutterwave-v3 which requires vlucas/phpdotenv 2.5 and your installation requires 5.4.1

Comment: Issue is that
i install the flutterwave package in over laravel project he give me 2 error 
1)Invalid argument flutterwavedev/flutterwave-v3. Use "composer require flutterwavedev/flutterwave-v3" instead to add packages to your composer.json.
when we run this give me 2nd error.
2) Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1 - flutterwavedev/flutterwave-v3 1.0.0 requires monolog/monolog 1.* -> found monolog/monolog[1.0.0-RC1, ..., 1.x-dev] but the package is fixed to 2.6.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `composer require abraham-flutterwave/laravel-payment`

The package supports Laravel 8 -> 10

https://github.com/bajoski34/Laravel

Answer (score 0):

I think currently flutter wave isn't compatible with Laravel 9 yet.